# How to erase a std::map cell by value using STL algorithms and functors?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I coded a small test entity manager in C++. I have a method called 'removeEntityByName' using a simple erase. Until here there is none problem. Now I have another method called 'removeEntityByPtr' which must delete by value. Here's the code which works :

```
void EntityManager::removeEntityByPtr(Entity *pEntity)
{
    std::map<std::string, Entity*>::iterator It = this->m_EntityList.begin();

    for (; It != this->m_EntityList.end();) {
        if ((*It).second == pEntity) {
            this->m_EntityList.erase(It++);
        } else {
            ++It;
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not very beautiful. So, I wondered if I could find a more elegant way using STL algorithms and functors to do the job correctly (I know there is no problem with std::vector but with std::map I'm not sure it works). So here's the different functors I tried to use:

```
template <typename T>
struct DeleteFunctor
{
    DeleteFunctor(T *pointer)
        :   m_Pointer(pointer)
    {

    }

    bool operator()(std::string, Entity *pEntity)
    {
        if (pEntity == this->m_Pointer) {
            delete(this->m_Pointer);
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    T *m_Pointer;
};

template <typename T>
struct DeleteFunctor
{
    DeleteFunctor(T *pointer)
        :   m_Pointer(pointer)
    {

    }

    bool operator()(std::pair<std::string, Entity*> const &cell)
    {
        if (cell.second == this->m_Pointer) {
            delete(this->m_Pointer);
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    T *m_Pointer;
};
```

And the STL algorithms :

```
this->m_EntityList.erase(std::remove(this->m_EntityList.begin(), this->m_EntityList.end(), DeleteFunctor<Entity>(pEntity)), this->m_EntityList.end());
```

I want to precise that the syntax is correct with Visual Studio. But the compilation failed.

Here's the compilation errors :

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>'
 with
[
   _Ty1=const std::string,
   _Ty2=Entity *
]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(507): peut être 'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(512): ou       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &)'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\exception(517): ou       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t)'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(426): ou       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) throw()'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(434): ou       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) throw()'
when attempting matching of the argument list '(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>, const DeleteFunctor)'
with
[
  _Ty1=const std::string,
  _Ty2=Entity *
]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm(1788) : see the reference of the model function '_FwdIt std::_Remove<std::_Tree_unchecked_iterator<_Mytree>,_Ty>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' en cours de compilation
with
[     _FwdIt=std::_Tree_unchecked_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,Entity *>>>>,
 _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,Entity *>>>,
 _Ty=DeleteFunctor
]
c:\users\volodia\desktop\testmanager\testmanager\entitymanager.cpp(76) : voir la référence à l'instanciation de la fonction modèle '_FwdIt std::remove<std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>,DeleteFunctor>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)' en cours de compilation
with
[
 _FwdIt=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,Entity *>>>>,
  _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,Entity *>>>,
  _Ty=DeleteFunctor
]
```

I tried several code combinations without any success. Does anyone can help me please ? Thanks a lot in advance foir your help.

Comment: you say compilation fails - but what is the error you get?

Comment: you could use Boost.MultiIndex with two ordered unique indices (over the string and over the Entity*)

Comment: that compilation error doesn't seem complete. And why do you complicate your functor with templates? just pass in an `Entity` alright. The operator() takes that hardcoded anyway as well

Comment: I would like to do the job done without Boost but thanks for your answer. I updated my question with the compilation error message. In fact my Entity class contains in propertie field which is the same than the std::map key. But the job is already done with my method called 'removeEntityByName'. But if it's possible I would like to delete using std::map value not espacially in my case but in a manner generally and without Boost. So I thaught functors usage could be a good choice and more it's elegant.

Comment: The usage of template is for the genericity of my code if I have several managers. I tried without template and it's the same thing. But maybe std::remove does not work with std::map container and functors can't be used with this.

Comment: I have updated a error messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many algorithms, including `std::remove` work by moving elements around in a container. For example, `std::remove` swaps unwanted elements to the back, and the wanted to the front.

This is not allowed in associative containers like `std::map` and `std::set`, because the order in wich elements are stored is fixed, so you can't use those algorithms on the containers.

Having said that, the first approach you made is correct, although you could separate the algorithm from the logic:

```
template <class Container, class Pred>
void erase_if(Container& cont, Pred pred) {
  for (auto first = begin(cont), last = end(cont); first != last;)
  {
    if (pred(*first))
      first = cont.erase(first);
    else
      ++first;
  }
}
```

And then in your code (C++14 style):

```
void EntityManager::removeEntityByPtr(Entity *pEntity)
{
  erase_if(this->m_EntityList, [=](auto const& keyValue) { 
    return keyValue.second == pEntity;
  }
}
```

**In C++11** you'll have to specify the type of the lambda function parameter, which is `std::pair<std::string const, Entity*>`.
**In C++03** you have to roll an extra functor, specify the iterator type inside the `erase_if` for loop like you did in your example, and call the `begin` and `end` member functions of the container instead of the free functions introduced in C++11

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. Bye.

Comment: +1 for tproviding the correct syntax. Just note that it is of `O(N)` complexity, whereas a `boost::bimap` or `boost::multi_index_container` would have `O(log N)` at the cost of an extra library dependency.